# Sybase IQ replication

Tags: replication, sybase, database-replication, sap-iq

I am using Sybase IQ 15, looking for a mechanism to replicate IQ tables to IQ replication server.

How to find if data has changed in IQ ( there are no triggers in IQ)

Able to replicate tables having timestamp and id columns.

Answer (score 1):

SAP IQ's transaction log can not be replicated by any tool. Even the vendor (SAP) does not support any program to do that.

If you want to replicate the changes from SAP IQ you need to provide some kind of your own CDC logic. For example you can provide a timestamp for every row and periodically run a query that copies rows modified since last run.

Or you can run periodically a full export of table data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by system views, whenever any data modification happens on sybase IQ tables , timestamp is captured in system view SYS.SYSIQTAB

SQL to find last data modified in table

`SELECT A.Table_id, T.table_name , dateformat(A.update_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.nnnnnn') LastModifiedTime FROM SYS.SYSIQTAB as A, SYS.SYSTABLE as T WHERE A.table_id = T.table_id AND T.table_name ='TableName'`